# How to kill TBannerAd?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Situation (Delphi Berlin 10.1):
in my application the main form calls the secondary form. Then the secondary form shows Admob's banner. The problem is even when I close the secondary form and clear the memory, the banner continues to be displayed. How to hide the banner completely? Thank you in advance.

Here's the code of the secondary unit:

```
unit ad_Unit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
  System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Advertising, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TAdForm = class(TForm)
    OKButton: TButton;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FBannerAd: TBannerAd;
  public
  end;

var
  AdForm: TAdForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TAdForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if Assigned(FBannerAd) then
  begin
    FBannerAd.Hide;
    FBannerAd.DisposeOf;
    FBannerAd := nil;
  end;
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;

procedure TAdForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBannerAd := TBannerAd.Create(Self);
  FBannerAd.Parent := Self;
  FBannerAd.AdUnitID := '<ID>';
  FBannerAd.Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
  FBannerAd.TestMode := True;
end;

procedure TAdForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBannerAd.LoadAd;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Does this happen on both iOS and Android, or one in particular? If so, please specify which. I'm guessing it's Android, because the code for TAndroidBannerAd looks suspicious to me

Comment: Yes, on Android. I didn't test this code on iOS.